# Вырезать ближайший родительский тег JS

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть такая интересная задачка:
В шаблоне HTML имеются места замены переменных на значения:

```
<div class="photo"><a href="/user/%id_user%" target="_blank" title="%name_user%"><img src="%photo_user%"></a></div>\
```

Т-е место **%name_user%** будет заменено на значение из переменной
 `var name_user = 'Ivan'`

Сейчас это делает моя функция.
Задача вот в чем, нужно вырезать тег, если эта подставляемые переменная(ые) **== null**
Допустим, **%photo_user% == null**, тогда выходной шаблон должен преобразиться до вида:

```
<div class="photo"><a href="/user/%id_user%" target="_blank" title="%name_user%"></a></div>\
```

Comment: Думаю, как можно определить текущий элемент по %name_user%, если я его определю - то в Jquery c легкостью удалю

Comment: Как различать `<img src="%photo_user%">` и `<div class="image-wrapper"><img src="%photo_user%"></div>`? Тут нужно выполнение по условию.

Comment: Сейчас условие на null, т-е каждая переменная photo_user, name_user, и тд проверяется. Если true, то нужно вырезать

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, я про то, что проще на этом этапе заложить функционал if/else, потому что будут блоки больше одного тега. Кроме того, есть проблема со "сканированием" такого тега - если переводить это в html-дерево, то непонятно, в чем искать ключевую фразу (контент? все атрибуты?), если искать по тексту, то можно выцепить что-то лишнее. Но в целом на данном этапе проще всего динамически составлять регулярку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте любой javascript micro templating, например [один из этих](http://microjs.com/#template) или [этот](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/), там есть «условия».

Comment: Ценный ответ!